# wordpress - How to check if a category is a child of another category?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a `WordPress` function to check if a category is a child of another category, something like `cat_is_ancestor_of()`.

Any one can help ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
function category_has_parent($catid){
    $category = get_category($catid);
    if ($category->category_parent > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use it as follows

```
if(category_has_parent('5')) // 5 is the category id
{
    echo "it has a parent !";
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer the original question, istead; you only show if a category is or not a parent category

Comment: @jepser, I answered exactly what the OP asked for and it's that, if a category has parent category or you can say if the category is a child of another category and in this case `$category->category_parent` will be grater than `0` if it's a child of another catrgory and for reference you may [check this out](http://wpseek.com/blog/2009/get-id-of-parent-category/49/), if you have any question then please feel free to ask... :-)

Comment: I think, the OP wants to know if category A is child of category B, not if category A or category B is a child category. If not I will Up 1 to your answer, but I don't think he wants to know that.

Comment: @jepser, From the OP's question `if a category is a child of another category`, hope it's crystal clear, thanks, anyway :-)